I have the best basis possible for a lattice. How well can I solve CVP?
Let's suppose I've given a lattice $L$. I'm allowed to spend as much pre-computation as I want to produce a poly-sized advice string, and I use it to find the best basis possible for the lattice.
Then I am given CVP challenges. I use Babai's nearest plane, with my high-quality basis, to solve CVP. How well do I do?
I can see from, e.g., http://www.noahsd.com/mini_lattices/05__babai.pdf, that I can solve $\gamma$-CVP with
$$\gamma = \sqrt{n+1}\max_{i\geq j}\frac{\Vert b_j^*\Vert}{\Vert b_i^*\Vert}$$
where $b_i^*$ are the Gram-Schmidt vectors from the lattice. So I would want this value to be as small as possible. But what guarantees can I have about this? Is there a worst-case lattice where this quantity is exponentially large? Is there an average-case behaviour?
I can see lots written to bound this quantity after LLL, or after some quantity of BKZ, but I want to know about the best possible.

Worth mentioning that you need to introduce some sort of normalization, otherwise a lattice like $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}\oplus 2^n \mathbb{Z}$ trivially has $\gamma \geq \sqrt{n}2^n$, but you probably view this as "boring". This can be fixed by mandating that $\det L = 1$, or studying $\gamma / \sqrt[n]{\det L}$.

In that lattice, can't I take $b_n=b_n^=(0,\dots,0,2^n)$ and $b_i=b_i^=e_i$ for $i\leq n-1$, so that I actually get $\gamma\leq \sqrt{n+1}$?

Yes, for some reason when I suggested that lattice I thought the quotient was $\lVert b_{\color{red}i}^\rVert / \lVert b_{\color{red}j}^\rVert$.

Theorem 2 of KF17 (seems to) state that one can take $\frac{\lVert b_j^*\rVert}{\lVert b_i^*\rVert} \leq \beta^{O((j-i)/\beta + \log \beta)}$ for any $\beta \leq n/2$. Setting $\beta = n/2$ and $j = n, i= 1$, this gives a bound of $\gamma \leq \sqrt{n}2^{O((\log n)^2)}$, so it does not appear that this quantity can be exponentially large.
It is also worth mentioning that your question may be rephrased in terms of the parameters $\ell_i := \log \lVert b_i^*\rVert$.
This parameterization has been somewhat popular in analyzing lattice reduction lately.
See Section 3 of Henninger and Ryan for a brief survey of them.
Of interest to you is probably Figure 1, where Henninger and Ryan depict experimental results how $\vec \ell$ "transforms" after LLL reduction for various (average-case) input distributions.
Henninger and Ryan even investigate the quantity
$
\mathsf{spread}(L) = \max_i \ell_i - \min_i \ell_i,
$
e.g. something similar to your quantity. Your exact quantity appears in the proof of Theorem 2 (and is related to their novel notion of reduced basis, Definition 3).
That being said though, I can only use their work to get $\lVert b_j^*\rVert/\lVert b_i^*\rVert \leq 2^{O(n)}$.
As they only consider poly-time lattice reduction, this makes some degree of sense.

Those are good references! But the best bound is still super-polynomial in $n$. I don't know whether that's to be expected or not, so I'll leave this as unanswered for a few more days. The dream would be to have $\gamma=O(1)$ with sufficient precomputation...

@SamJaques Do you require the preprocessed information to be a basis? If it is just some general poly-sized amount of advice, you can do better. The problem is "Search CVPP" (CVP with Preprocessing). See for example On the Closest Vector Problem with a Distance Guarantee by Dadush, Regev, and Stephens-Davidowitz. They get approximation factor $O(n/\sqrt{\log n})$ with other techniques, and mention in Section 1.2 that the bound I quoted above (using KZ basis) is the best known (as of 10 years ago).

This work also appears to be relevant, and more specifically focused on your problem.
